# Checkerboard Pattern css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of div elements that I'm currently displaying in four columns using CSS float. I would like to "alternate" the background-color of these elements. If I simply use nth-child(even) or nth-child(odd) I get the same color in each column vertically. But i want it like this:

```
1blue  2green 3blue  4green
5green 6blue  7green 8blue
9blue ...
```

I really don't get it. Tried 4n+1 and so on, nothing works as expected.

Comment: Can you please provide your code in jsfiddle? So that I can help you.

Comment: @RonitMukherjee https://jsfiddle.net/1f898yru/ you see, first and second row are alternating the same way, not like on a checkerboard

Comment: It's fixed that u will have 4 cols?

Comment: yes it is fixed to 4 cols. But would be interesting to have a sample calculation to get known how it works with 4/6/8 and so on cols...

Comment: Since you're using "float" layout, CSS cannot tell which one is on first line and which ones are on 2nd line etc. Unless you wrap each 4 columns in a div like what @VXp did in his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this css:

```
div:nth-of-type(8n+2),
div:nth-of-type(8n+4),
div:nth-of-type(8n+5),
div:nth-of-type(8n+7)
{ background-color: green}
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1f898yru/4/

Comment: This works perfectly if the OP's desire is to have exactly 8 divs

Comment: this completely solves the problem for 4 cols. Nice one. And it also works for more than 8 divs. see: https://jsfiddle.net/1f898yru/5/

Comment: could you provide a general solution for a number of N cols to calculate... @Cons7an7ine ?

Comment: @Gooze did you tried https://jsfiddle.net/0n7za4ex/1/ ?

Comment: @RonitMukherjee yes i did. it works, but it need additional markup. Cons7an7ine Solution does not need additional markup and is a css-only solution, thatswhy i prefer....

Comment: @Gooze but this solution is for specific column/ row count. When going with dynamic programming, my approach would come handy.

Answer (score -1):

Since i've mistaken first time i'll update my answer here :

```
<ul>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
  </ul>  
  <ul>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
    <li>block</li>
  </ul>

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -4px;
      padding: 0;
      width: 25%;
    }

    ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    ul:nth-child(even) li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: green;
    }

    ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: green;
    }
    ul:nth-child(odd) li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

--- old answer ---
Why wouldn't you use li tag instead of div tag ?

HTML

```
<ul id='myblocklist>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#myblocklist {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul#myblocklist li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#myblocklist li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
ul#myblocklist li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I wrote this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/ludovic-reus/pen/wPxLRE) if it can be of any help.

Comment: Problem is completely the same if i use <li> see: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xPJovR

Comment: That doesn't solve anything

Comment: This solution is not too helpful

Comment: Ok my mistake,
Then i would advice to put each or your 'lines' in a list and the combine odd / even css  on ul and li tags
[see fork from your codepen](https://codepen.io/ludovic-reus/pen/ooMKxo)

Answer (score -1):

I have tried creating the required checkbox. Kindly refer the fiddle for better understanding
https://jsfiddle.net/0n7za4ex/1/

```
//HTML
<div id="checkboard">
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="to box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
  <div class="fro box"></div>
</div>

//CSS
#checkboard {
  padding: 5%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#checkboard .box {
  width: 24%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#checkboard .to.box:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}

#checkboard .to.box:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: blue;
}

#checkboard .fro.box:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: blue;
}

#checkboard .fro.box:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}
#checkboard .box:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  background: red;
}

#checkboard .box:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
```